# Local database in Windows Phone 8.1 Uniwersal (Lib)

Tags: database, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

So here's my question how can i save to local database in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal **without** using external libraries.

So answer install/add nuget package is not an answer.

I'm creating library and as company specified i can not use any libraries, tho i need to save some of user data to database, as this data might be even few thousand records i don't want to think about saving it through IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings,

In my old project(8.0) i used LinqToSql, so bonus points if this wouldn't need from me to change too much code.

Comment: Are you making up all these restrictions?

Comment: Not me but my employer.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using Linq To SQL with phone 8,1 Silverlight app, but I do not know of any in-the-box solution with 8,1 Universal

Comment: Yep, i already did part of 8.1 silverlight, (worked almost out of the box), but need universal as well )